# What does golang.org/x/text/message.Print accomplish?

Tags: go, internationalization, translation

The doc for [`Printer.Print`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/message#Printer.Print) says:

> Print is like fmt.Print, but using language-specific formatting.

but I'm having difficult seeing anything language specific compared to [`Printer.Printf`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/message#Printer.Printf).

Consider:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "golang.org/x/text/language"
    "golang.org/x/text/message"
)

func main() {
    message.SetString(language.English, "foo", "bar")

    p := message.NewPrinter(language.English)
    p.Print("foo")
    fmt.Println()
    p.Printf("foo")
    fmt.Println()
}
```

Result:

```
foo
bar
```

What exactly does `Printer.Print` do (that is language specific)?

Answer (score 2):

> Package message implements formatted I/O for localized strings with functions analogous to the fmt's print functions. It is a drop-in replacement for fmt.

Language-specific behavior does not distinguish `Printer.Print` from `Printer.Printf` -- rather it distinguishes each from their [analogous functions in the `fmt` package](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Print).  It's right there in the documentation you quoted.

Comment: I still don't understand it. Why does `Print` not do language lookups? Because `Print` is supposed to print its arguments verbatim, without any interpretation?